# Merge two columns and create a new column using SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to merge 2 columns in a view and create new column in pgAdmin.

Like, I have first name and last name in a table, and I want to combine these 2 columns and create a new column called `fullname`.

Can anyone suggest a workable solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a *computed column* to your table. Will always have up-to-date data!

```
alter table tablename
    add fullname varchar(50) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (firstname || lastname) stored;
```

Where you specify data type and length as the sum of firstname's and lastname's data types. (E.g. varchar(25) + varchar(25) -> varchar(50).)

**Edit:** Or create a view:

```
create view viewname as
select t.*, t.firstname || t.lastname as fullname
from tablename t
```

Comment: Can we do the same thing in view? Instead of table